# "Connection to server got closed. Server will not be restarted." popping up again and again

Tags: c++, c, json, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode on Ubuntu 20.04.

The errors, **"Connection to server got closed. Server will not be restarted."** and **"The language server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. It will not be restarted."** are popping up again and again for a reason that I cannot figure out:
[image]

[image]

So far, I have done the following:

1. Restarted VSCode
2. Restarted my PC
3. Opened VSCode by going to that specific folder in the file explorer, right-clicking and selecting open in terminal, and typing "code ."
4. Uninstalling and reinstalling the C/C++ Extension
5. Downgrading the C++ extnsion
6. Using the pre-release C++ extension
7. Modifying the c_cpp_properties.json

Here is my current c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening and/or how it could be fixed?

Comment: When you get the error, are you actively coding or does it happen if you just leave it alone for some time too? Just to confirm, it's the Microsoft C/C++ extension, version 1.12.4, right?

Comment: clearing the vscode folders would probably be a good start. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=language-service.yml for debugging instructions and to raise an issue if you can't fix it

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to the extensions, then look for the problematic extension causing the issue. Right-click on the extension, choose 'install another version,' and select an alternative version to install. Hopefully, this will resolve the problem.